# How to deploy qt5 qml plugin to android?

Tags: android, qml, qt5

I am trying to import TimeExample Qt Quick Extension Plugin from Qt 5.1.0 android installation.

`libqmlqtimeexampleplugin.so` is built sucessfully in `build-plugins-Android_for_arm_GCC_4_6_Qt_5_1_0-Debug/imports`

Then I created simple Qt Quick2 Application (built-in Elements) from Qt Creator. What should I add to application project file to get QML plugin in output ".apk" package?

Now it says:

> W/Qt      (23528): assets:/qml/TimeExampleTest/main.qml:2 (): assets:/qml/TimeExampleTest/main.qml:2:1: module "TimeExample" is not installed

main.qml

```
 import QtQuick 2.0

 import TimeExample 1.0 // import types from the plugin

 Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MouseArea {
       anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
          Qt.quit();
       }
    }

   Clock { // this class is defined in QML (imports/TimeExample/Clock.qml)

        Time { // this class is defined in C++ (plugin.cpp)
            id: time
      }

        hours: time.hour
      minutes: time.minute

    }
}
```

TimeExampleTest.pro

```
folder_01.source = qml/TimeExampleTest

 folder_01.target = qml

 folder_02.source = /home/artem/Projects/Veedo/Test/build-plugins-Android_for_arm_GCC_4_6_Qt_5_1_0-Debug/imports/TimeExample

 folder_02.target = imports

 DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = folder_01 folder_02

 QML_IMPORT_PATH = /home/artem/Projects/Veedo/Test/build-plugins-Android_for_arm_GCC_4_6_Qt_5_1_0-Debug/imports/TimeExample

 SOURCES += main.cpp

 include(qtquick2applicationviewer/qtquick2applicationviewer.pri)

 qtcAddDeployment()

 OTHER_FILES += \
    android/src/org/kde/necessitas/ministro/IMinistro.aidl \
    android/src/org/kde/necessitas/ministro/IMinistroCallback.aidl \
    android/src/org/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings/QtActivity.java \
    android/src/org/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings/QtApplication.java \
    android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    android/version.xml \
    android/res/values-ja/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-rs/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-zh-rTW/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-fa/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-ru/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-fr/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-ro/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-el/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-ms/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-nb/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-et/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-pl/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-pt-rBR/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-es/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-id/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-de/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-it/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-zh-rCN/strings.xml \
    android/res/values/strings.xml \
    android/res/values/libs.xml \
    android/res/layout/splash.xml \
    android/res/values-nl/strings.xml
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Qt 5.3, we managed to get our QML plugin recognized by a Qt Android app only by deploying the plugin to the QT_INSTALL_QML directory where official Qt QML modules reside. This directory is /opt/Qt/5.3/android_armv7/qml in our case.

**Plugin Side**

Our `.pro` file for the plugin looks like:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = prova
QT += qml quick multimedia
CONFIG += qt plugin c++11 console
CONFIG -= android_install
TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)
uri = com.mycompany.qmlcomponents

# Input
SOURCES += \
    src1.cpp \
    src2.cpp

HEADERS += \
    src1.h \
    src2.h

##The below is generated automatically by Qt Creator when you create a new "Qt Quick 2 Extension Plugin" project for Android

#Copies the qmldir file to the build directory
!equals(_PRO_FILE_PWD_, $$OUT_PWD) {
    copy_qmldir.target = $$OUT_PWD/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.depends = $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.commands = $(COPY_FILE) \"$$replace(copy_qmldir.depends, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)\" \"$$replace(copy_qmldir.target, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)\"
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copy_qmldir
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$copy_qmldir.target
}

#Copies the qmldir file and the built plugin .so to the QT_INSTALL_QML directory
qmldir.files = qmldir
unix {
    installPath = $$[QT_INSTALL_QML]/$$replace(uri, \\., /)
    qmldir.path = $$installPath
    target.path = $$installPath
    INSTALLS += target qmldir
}
```

Our `qmldir` (in the plugin source tree root) file is:

```
module com.mycompany.qmlcomponents
plugin prova
```

**Application Side**

The .pro file looks like:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick widgets multimedia

CONFIG+= console
SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =
# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH,armeabi-v7a) {
    ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS = \
        /opt/Qt/5.3/android_armv7/qml/com/mycompany/qmlcomponents/libprova.so
}
```

We don't actually know if the inclusion of the extra libprova.so is necessary. It's most probably not.

The `main.cpp` looks like:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

The `main.qml` just includes the plugin like:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtMultimedia 5.0

import com.mycompany.qmlcomponents 1.0

...
```

**Building and Deployment**

The way we build and deploy the plugin is to `qmake` (from the android-armv7 toolchain of Qt), then `make install`. It installs the qmldir file and the plugin .so to the QT_INSTALL_QML directory.

The way we build and deploy the project that uses the plugin is to `qmake` (again, from the android-armv7 toolchain of Qt), then `make install INSTALL_ROOT=.` (installs to build directory), then run `androiddeployqt`. The last command creates the Android project structure with the qmldirs in assets/ and libraries in libs/ and bundles the whole thing in an apk via `ant`. For the details of this procedure, refer to http://qt-project.org/wiki/Android.

In short, we were only able to get our QML plugin recognized inside an Android project by putting it inside the private Qt qml directory.

Comment: Interesting, but iirc there's a much more straightforward way, I could dig / try some code if you are interested.

Comment: I am interested @mlvljr !

Comment: @user981733 OK, let me look into this in the following days then :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading Qt's source about QAbstractFileEngineHandler, I found something ugly in Qt:

1. Qt does implemented some kind of mechanism to provide "searchpath" (not URL) like "qrc:", "assets:", where the kernel is QAbstractFileEngineHandler.
2. QAbstractFileEngineHandler becomes no longer public in Qt5, it only provide abstract to QFile, QFileInfo, QDir, QIcon, and things provided by QFile, including QImage, plus QAndroidAssetsFileEngineHandler, which is specialized for Android assets.
3. So SearchPath schema is not compatible with QUrl even they look so similar, as you know QtQuick is setSource to some URL, so a qml file would not loaded by "assets:" prefix directly.
4. You can find this below `[static] void QDir::setSearchPaths(const QString &prefix, const QStringList &searchPaths)` in Qt's document:

   ```
   QDir::setSearchPaths("icons", QStringList(QDir::homePath() + "/images"));
   QDir::setSearchPaths("docs", QStringList(":/embeddedDocuments"));

   ...    
   QPixmap pixmap("icons:undo.png"); // will look for undo.png in QDir::homePath() + "/images"    
   QFile file("docs:design.odf"); // will look in the :/embeddedDocuments resource path
   ```

   You will find this snippet not work because QPixmap did not load image from QAbstractFileEngineHandler, may this be Qt's undocumented changes. On the other hand, QtCore unit test about searchpath only tested on QFile

Further more, `void addResourceSearchPath(const QString &path)` is obsoleted, however setSearchPath is defective, I feel pretty confused on this. Maybe I should take a look in QUrl now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got this done.

Add this to your application code:

```
QQuickView *m_view;
m_view->engine()->addImportPath("assets:/");
m_view->engine()->addPluginPath(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
```

Forward slash after "assets:" is important, it won't work without it.
In your build folder you need to have directory structure like this: `/home/my_name/project_build_directory/qml/my_plugin`. Your plugin directory should have your `.so` library and the `qmldir` file.
Then you need to get the plugin packaged. This should be possible by adding the following to your `.pro` file:

```
ANDROID_EXTRA_PLUGINS += /full/path/to/your/plugin/folder
```

This however didn't work for me with Qt Creator from Qt 5.11 so what I had to do was to add this manually to the `.json` deployment file :

```
"android-extra-plugins":"/full/path/to/your/plugin",
```

The build variable might work in earlier versions of the Qt Creator.
If your plugins have Qt dependencies they will not be picked up by androiddeployqt, you will have to add them manually. This is done by either adding a build variable to the .pro file:

```
ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS += /your/qt/path/lib/libQt5Xml.so
... etc
```

or if that doesn't work, you'll have to add this manually to the JSON build file:

```
"android-extra-libs":"/your/qt/path/lib/libQt5Xml.so,/your/qt/path/lib/libQt5Network.so",
...etc
```

The process is messy, the JSON file is automatically regenerated on some changes to the build so the changes will have to be pasted to it again. If anyone knows how to improve the process this would be appreciated. What you should end up with on your android device is, your plugin `.so` will end up in the same directory all `.so` libraries are in and your `qmldir` will end up in `assets:/your_plugin_name/qmldir`.